# Same tax for all territories and tax-free products

Tags: 8, commerce

We're selling registrations to a congress through Drupal Commerce 2 and have been informed by the government of the country where the conference takes place that we have to charge their local tax to all attendees. Our attendees come from all over the world.

Is there a way to configure the Commerce 2 tax module to have it charge the same tax rate to all orders, regardless of where the customer is, other than creating a custom tax type and adding all territories one by one?

We also sell other products and do not want this local tax applied to those products. How would we go about configuring those products so they are not included in the tax calculation?

Comment: I would really want to know how to do this also. Did you managed to find out and answer?

Answer (score 2):

(Answering my own question.)

I ended up not using Commerce's Tax module but coding my own.  I added a "Taxable" field to products and created an **Order Processor plugin** to calculate the tax amount and add it to orders as an adjustment.

It took much longer to figure out how to do it than to actually do it.